# C# Visual Studio 2008 NumericUpDown PopUp Menu Removal

Tags: visual-studio, menu, popup, numericupdown

[MenuPic](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/20cbca189e.jpg)

Greetings. I am using the NumericUpDown control on my application. When I right click mouse on any of these controls the popup menu shows up as displayed in the above link.

How do I remove this menu please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an empty context menu to the controls

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
this.numericUpDown1.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
this.numericUpDown2.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
```